# Обновить дату, если с момента последнего обновления прошло 7 дней

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, дата

Пока что составил такой запрос

```
mysqli_query($CONNECT, '
    UPDATE `agrousadby` 
    SET `date` = NOW() 
    WHERE `id` = '.$Param['id'].' 
    AND `date` < (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY))
');
```

но не работает. Пишет "ошибка синтаксиса SQL-запроса" (You have an error in your SQL syntax).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Насколько я вижу, у вас лишняя скобка в конце запроса. Должно быть так:

```
mysqli_query($CONNECT, '
    UPDATE `agrousadby` 
    SET `date` = NOW() 
    WHERE `id` = '.$Param['id'].' 
    AND `date` < (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
');
```

*Пожалуйста, уточняйте, что значит "не работает". Запрос может не возвращать нужные данные, а может падать с синтаксической ошибкой. А скобку легко не заметить и пойти по ложному пути в поисках.*

Comment: Да, лишняя скобка была, но всё-ровно может кому код пригодится)